# question marks instead of text in excel export from DB2 via SQL Developer

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper, db2-zos

Does anyone do exports to excel from DB2 via SQL developer? I have a field in my table which doesn't get exported right, but comes full of question marks instead. All the other fields are fine. This field doesn't contain anything special, just numbers and standard latin characters. I don't know in which enconding it is and how to check it, alas - tried options like "Default", "UTF-8" and "CP-1251", as program suggests on export form, but it still comes out as a bunch of question marks. I know z/OS uses EBCDIC, but there's nothing like that in the encodings list. Does anyone has any idea on how to fix it? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: EDIT your question to show the code that you run in SQL-Developer to perform the export from Db2.

Comment: platform and version of Db2?

Comment: everything SQLDev spits out is UTF-8, because it's a java program, and that's what Java does

Comment: @mao it's not a code, it's a built-in export option.

Comment: @Charles z/OS 2.3 and DB2 12.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith good to know, thank you, I'm quite new in all this stuff :)

Comment: Look in SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS table (where TBCREATOR, TBNAME match the schema and table-name) and the CCSID column value may show the encoding.  Or ask your Z DBA for help.  In the export wizard, the encoding value must be compatible with the CCSID. You can also use the wizard to export to text or delimited and view the characters in notepad to see if the codepage conversion is breaking before excel sees it.

Comment: @mao CCSID says 278, which means "FIN/SWEDEN EBCDIC" according to IBM, but that's what I tried as a very first option just because I work with Swedish service on mainframe - and it gives me just the same set of question marks in Excel as UTF-8 and Default options. Export to text though works and shows me the proper field content.

Comment: If Export to TEXT shows correct characters, that means the flaw lies either in Excel or in the SQL-Developer-code (i.e. the Db2 driver is working correctly).  You can export to CSV or delimited and get Excel to open that file directly (instead of exporting to XLS/XLSX directly which seems to give you the symptom).

Comment: Additionally, if you are adept with Excel you can directly pull data from Db2 tables into Excel via odbc/get external data. In other words, you don't need Oracle-SQL-Developer at all.

Comment: @mao CSV in IBM-278 gives a totally crazy block of symbols for all the fields, CSV in both UTF-8 and Default (CP-1251) gives a list of column names without any data inside. Delimited in default encoding gives a list of column names as well. I guess, I'm cursed. I used to work with external data in Excel though, but somehow have never tried it with DB2. Will go check if getting ODBC connection to DB2 will be easier than getting JDBC one which took my colleagues a couple of months recently :)

Comment: @mao thank you so much for all the comments, anyway! It's a good chance for me to get to know something new about all this stuff I'm working with now :)

Comment: Exporting to text/delimited/csv (via SQL-Developer-wizard) to encoding ISO8859_15 should deliver correct codepage conversions from CCSID 278. If it does not, then consider opening a ticket with Oracle support.  In addition to using ODBC/Get-External-Data directly within Excel, you also may have a suitable Db2-client installed that lets you use the Db2-command-line (db2cmd.exe) to connect to the Db2/ZOS and run the export to CSV at the command-line. So you have more than one option.

Comment: @mao ISO8859_15 does the trick for The Cursed Column in CSV: data is shown properly. But 6 of 12 other columns come up blank. I'll talk to our DB people about other options though.